# Mapbox reverse geocoding does not always return a result

Tags: android, mapbox, reverse-geocoding

Im trying [reverse geocoding example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/geocoder/#reverse-geocoding) on mapbox

Everything's working fine. But the problem is when i replace my current location it doesnt return a result.
I think that mapbox doesnt have much data about my region (Im in Vietnam). Is there anyway to add my own places supposed that I had a dataset of coordinate and address

My code:

```
mapboxGeocoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
                .query(Point.fromLngLat(106.799142,10.875838))
                .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
                .build();;

        mapboxGeocoding.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

                List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();

                if (results.size() > 0) {

                    // Log the first results Point.
                    //Point firstResultPoint = results.get(0).center();
                    String country=results.get(0).placeName();
                    Log.d("Geocoding",country);
                } else {

                    // No result for your request were found.

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResponse: No result found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mapboxGeocoding.cancelCall();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way of adding custom POIs to the data powering the Geocoding API, but the workaround is to use the [Tilequery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tilequery-api/). This API retrieves features from vector tiles based on proximity to a particular geographic coordinate. You can mimic reverse geocoding functionality with custom POIs via the following workflow:

1. Create a tileset which contains your Custom POIs. That is, [upload your data as a tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/tilequery-healthy-food-finder/#upload-the-data-as-a-tileset).
2. Retrieve the geographic coordinates of the point that you would like to use for reverse geocoding.
3. Make a call to the Tilequery API where radius is 0, tileset_id is the id of the tileset you created in step 1, and {lon},{lat} are the longitude and latitude retrieved in step 2. More details about each of these parameters can be found [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-features-from-vector-tiles).

I'd recommend working through this [tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/tilequery-healthy-food-finder/) on making a healthy food finder with the Tilequery API, to gain more intuition about how the API can be used for reverse geocoding with custom POIs. The [Tilequery API playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/) is also an excellent resource for interactive experimentation.

Let me know if something is unclear!

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try it now. And the tut app is pretty similiar to my app in someway